# Flutter list mapping, filtering

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

so i have this data that I compare with a date range that is requested by the user if the Days list is the same as my transaction date then I put it in that date, and will return a new list

```
List transactionss = [
    {'date': '2023-02-06', 'amount': 250000, 'type': 0},
    {'date': '2023-02-06', 'amount': 30000, 'type': 1}
  ];

  final daysToGenerates = DateTime.parse('2023-02-07')
      .difference(DateTime.parse('2023-02-01'))
      .inDays;
  List dayss = List.generate(
      daysToGenerates,
      (i) => DateTime(
          DateTime.parse('2023-02-01').year,
          DateTime.parse('2023-02-01').month,
          DateTime.parse('2023-02-01').day + (i)));

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> dats = [];
  for (DateTime date in dayss) {
    for (Map<String, dynamic> transaction in transactionss) {
      DateTime transactionDate = DateTime.parse(transaction['date']);
      if (date == transactionDate) {
        dats.add(transaction);
      } else {
        dats.add({
          'date': date.toString().substring(0, 10),
          'amount': 0,
          'type': 5
        });
      }
    }
  }


     sample result      [
      {date: 2023-02-01, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-01, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-02, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-02, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-03, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-03, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-04, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-04, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-05, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-05, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-06, amount: 250000, type: 0}, 
      {date: 2023-02-06, amount: 30000, type: 1}, 
      {date: 2023-02-07, amount: 0, type: 5}, 
      {date: 2023-02-07, amount: 0, type: 5}
     ]

            sample FL_chart Spot
                       spot: dataset.where((element) => (element['type'] == 0 ||
                              element['type'] == 5))
                          .mapIndexed((index, e) {
                        return FlSpot(
                            index as double, double.parse(amount));
                      }).toList()
```

now my problem is why does the dates double? because the 'dataset'(the list that it returns) will be used in fl chart, and because its doubling dates my x axis on chart is getting double dates also becuase that index that just shouldve been 7 for example doubles and becomes 14, what are my options here? filter? hope you understand my question

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: You iterate over all days, and within each iteration, you iterate over all transactions.  Each of those inner iterations always adds one element to `dats`.  Therefore if you have *m* days and *n* transactions, `dats` will end up with *m* \* *n* elements.  There will be *n* elements for each date, one for each transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the second for loop, if i get it right, you want that in case you didn't find any transactions to add a zero transaction in the list.

Now what your code does, is for every transaction that doesn't have the date equals to the date you check, it will add a new "zero" transaction.

The easiest fix for your issue is to add a simple flag that will be set to true when you find a transaction, if the flag is still false, then add a zero transaction.

```
 List transactionss = [
    {'date': '2023-02-06', 'amount': 250000, 'type': 0},
    {'date': '2023-02-06', 'amount': 30000, 'type': 1}
  ];

  final daysToGenerates = DateTime.parse('2023-02-07')
      .difference(DateTime.parse('2023-02-01'))
      .inDays;
  List dayss = List.generate(
      daysToGenerates,
      (i) => DateTime(
          DateTime.parse('2023-02-01').year,
          DateTime.parse('2023-02-01').month,
          DateTime.parse('2023-02-01').day + (i)));

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> dats = [];
  for (DateTime date in dayss) {
    // this for depends on the number of types you have.
    // you need to do adjust the for based on min/max type value
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      bool didFindTransaction = false;
      for (Map<String, dynamic> transaction in transactionss) {
        DateTime transactionDate = DateTime.parse(transaction['date']);
        final type = transaction['type'];      
        if (date == transactionDate && type == i) {
          dats.add(transaction);
          didFindTransaction = true;
        }
      }
      if (!didFindTransaction) {
        dats.addAll([
          {'date': date.toString().substring(0, 10), 'amount': 0, 'type': i}
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

If i get it right, you want values for all types and dates, and if there is no value for that pair date and type it should be set to zero.

Check out my updated answer.

Comment: this answered my question, thank you! lastly now do you have an Idea on a work around on how'd I plot this in fl chart properly, because now the way I plot is this 
                       spot: dataset.where((element) => (element['type'] == 0 ||
                              element['type'] == 5))
                          .mapIndexed((index, e) {
                        return FlSpot(
                            index as double, double.parse(amount));
                      }).toList()

Comment: now when the i filter out the types, on one linebar data i only filter out the type 0's and 5's which is so but now, since the other types out filtered out like 1, then their data and date will be gone in the line, now there is a gap in the dates

Comment: @user3352042 I'm sorry but i don't quite get your problem. Would you be able to edit the question and add some details there ?

Comment: my bad haha my english is not that good, so in my question at the bottom there is a fl linechart data spot you can use that.. this is where i can map the dataset to a list that accepts an x and y data, the date and the amounts, all in all i have 4 fl spots. for 4 types.. now in each of my map there I used 'where' to filter out the other types in each spot (linebar).. so comes the problem when i filter (use where) the type 0 for example - then the other transactions with types that are not 0 will be gone and along with its dates, so now the dataset will be incomplete of 1 or more dates

Comment: is my approach wrong? cuz in each spot(linebar) I want the full range of date then will filter it out by type of transaction, should my dataset be just solo List per type?

Comment: you are brilliant, thank you so much, and i've learned something new!